# Type Mismatch on cell.value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code.

I have a table that contains several #N/A and therefore I have to change them into "Missing data". not too difficult. But in two specif columns, the data are dates. When the table is created the columns are in type "General" and therefore the dates are expressed in numbers.

My problem is that I want to set the columns in Date type and delete all those cells that had the value of 0 (or 01/01/1900 when in date type). I have this code but it says error type mismatch.

I can't copy all the code because is very long

```
sub datachange()
dim cell as range

      For Each cell In Range("EntireTable")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(cell.Value) = True Then
            cell.Value = "Missing Data"
        End If
      Next cell

   For Each cell In Range("EntireTable").Columns(6)
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.Value = "Missing Information"
        End If
    Next cell
    Range("EntireTable").Columns(6).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

end sub
```

Comment: `If cell.Value = 0 Then` will error if the cell contains an error. You could use `Range.SpecialCells` to fix the errors instead of looping.

Comment: Well maybe the cell has text in it. Anyway - you can use `Range.Replace` instead of the entire 2nd loop.

Comment: *I can't copy all the code because is very long* - make it shorter. Break your procedure down into smaller, more specialized ones. Thank yourself later.

Answer (score 1):

As @BigBen mentioned in comments that if the cell contains an error, you will get the `Type Mismatch` error. You can use [**IsError**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function) function which returns a `Boolean` value (True/False) indicating whether an expression is an error value.

Change `If cell.Value = 0 Then` to `If IsError(cell.Value) Then`